# Search is broken on meta

Tags: support, search, meta

When I do a search like 'intitle:1 +user' on meta, I get proper results in the 'relevance' tab. I switch to the 'votes' tab and all the results don't have 'user' in the title. Seems to be broken. It works fine on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because [a new Search system is being tested here on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test).

Among other changes, `intitle` was changed to `title`. And instead of being a flag, you have to input your title stuff in quotes.

So your desired search would be [`title:"user"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3a"user"&tab=votes). This link shows the votes tab, which does work with the correct syntax.