# New search is broken on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, search

[Two days ago, I posted about the search on Meta not working properly when switching from the relevance tab to the votes tab.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76544/search-is-broken-on-meta/76546#76546) The answer I accepted is that they were doing testing. Now I see SO has the new search **with the same broken behavior**!

Why can't I switch to the votes tab and get results using the filter criteria I specified?

Comment: Did you use filter criteria correctly? Can you tell us what your search parameter was?

Comment: Do any search for any keyword in title (example: title: +user +name) and then switch to votes tab. All the results don't contain 'user' nor 'name' in their titles anymore. This feature used to work and I was using it heavily.

Comment: The options have changed slightly, the syntax is now `+title:` (like the + preceding any other term), this is the intended behavior.

Answer (score 5):

It appears there's been some changes to the [search syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search) that make your previous queries fail.

Try one of the following (thanks @GraceNote):

`+title:user +title:name` : question title must have "user" AND "name"
 `+title:"user name"`: question title must contain the string "user name"
 `title:user title:name` : questions are returned if "user" or "name" is in the title

They appear to return the results you mention in your comment and work when changing between tabs.

Comment: Your answer here is more correct than mine, but to elaborate: `+title:user +title:name` will return you all results where the title has user AND name. If one prefers differently, `title:"user" title:"name"` will return all results where the title has user OR name. Grouping them as `+title:"user name"` will specifically get the string "user name" in the title.

Comment: You know my question is not about the search syntax but the fact that when you switch tabs, results are not correct? The same syntax should work on any tab. While your syntax works, it's not documented at http://stackoverflow.com/search. Isn't the plus sign attached to keyword and not the search criteria filter?

Comment: @Tony If you check out the searches that yhw42 and I concocted, you'll notice that the behavior properly carries over to the Votes tab - [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2btitle%3auser%20%2btitle%3aname). The reason your attempt didn't reflect is because the search wasn't properly structured - you ended up filtering questions that have mention of user or name but not necessarily in the title. Compare how [`+user +name` alone](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Buser+%2Bname) returns with how your test went.

Comment: @Grace: in this case the documentation is not clear. I have always used syntax like intitle:1 +apples +oranges which worked between tabs. I figured the new search is about more concise search syntax. 'title:' instead of 'intitle:1'. The new docs mentions an example: title:apples oranges. Does this mean apples is only in the title or both apples AND oranges?? It's not clear.

Comment: @Tony Nay, it isn't clear.

Comment: I will post another question about this.

Comment: thanks for telling, is that what got changed in 2011.1.28.9?