# Documentation on Search is not clear and it's confusing

Tags: discussion, search

The search on SO has changed and the new syntax through me off and I thought it was broken. I posted about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76951/new-search-is-broken-on-stack-overflow).

This search syntax used to work before: `intitle: +oranges +apples`. This means show me posts which have 'oranges' AND 'apples' only in their title. If I switched to the votes tab, I get posts with these keywords only. Basically re-sort the results. Worked perfect.

Based on answers I got, to get the **same** results with the new syntax AND with tab switching I have to enter `+title:oranges +title:apples`. Would you ever figure this out if you read the current Search documentation and examples at https://stackoverflow.com/search?

It says to put the + sign along with the keywords, at least based on this docs snippet. I wouldn't figure that + sign is in front the filter criteria instead of the keyword:

```
to ensure that the words appear in the results
+apples +oranges
```

and then this example:

```
questions with specific words in the title  title:apples
title:apples oranges
```

If you read the docs and examples and you want to ensure both must appear in the title, you would think to use `title: +apples +oranges`. You get results with both in the title. If you do `+title:oranges +title:apples', you also get results with both in the title but they are different than the first set or at least not in the same order. (I did a visualk comparsion). But first syntax breaks when you switch tabs.

When you read the search docs page, where would you figure to put the '+' sign, with the keywords or with the search criteria filter? If you look at the examples, you don't see `+title` or +user or `+hasaccepted` or `+votes` ...etc being used.

Long story short, the docs need rewriting with more explanations.